# Extract email id from iOS web view

Tags: ios, uiwebview, push-notification

I am using APPLE PUSH NOTIFICATION for my application, I implemented it and it works fine. Here I want one additional thing, I want to extract email id from webview when users logs in, and associate it with devicetoken and send it to my server in order to send push notifications based on email id and devicetoken both. Any one who can help me out. First some one tell me whether it is possible to get email id from html or not?? If yes, how can I extract it??

Comment: Did you tried any thing?

Comment: i did the complete work for implementing push notifications, it works good. But now i need to get email from web view. And i am not sure about it, whether it is possible or not.  @JayprakashDubey

Comment: Not sure if this suits your needs, but you can perform JavaScript on UIWebView with -stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:. (so you can extract anything from a page)

Comment: ok, thanks.. what could be the appropriate solution to this problem?? @MANIAK_dobrii